# model validation unittest using Moq

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, moq

Hi i am trying to validate model field as required but result is always comming null, I am expecting model will send me error as First name is requied but nothing happening

here is my unittest using Moq

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize() { 
    RepositoryMoc= new Mock<ITestRepository>(); 
    _service = new TestService(RepositoryMoc.Object) 
}

[TestMethod]
public void UpdateResults_FirstNameRequied() {

    User u = new User();
    u.FirstName = "";
    u.LastName = "Lee";

    RepositoryMoc.Setup(r => r.UpdateResults(u));           
    var result = _service.UpdateResults(u);          
    Assert.AreEqual("FirstName is required", result.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've wrote a setup for RepositoryMoc, but it not returning something. If you want that function to return something, write a setup like that:

```
RepositoryMoc.Setup(r => r.UpdateResults(u)).Returns(<WhateverItHasToReturn>);
```

Comment: but i want to expect from model to return First name is required, Actually i want to test data anotation.

Comment: So, which class do you want to test and what are you mocking away?

Comment: I am mocking out my repository and from service i am expecting error First name is required, Actually i am teting my data anotation which is in the model.